# How to obtain this xml android layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, layout, android-gridlayout

I've seen this layout ( http://cdn0.tnwcdn.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/1/files/2014/03/Instaedit1.jpg ) and i wanna do somthing like that but i don't know what i have to do to obtain that result.
i've tried with a relative layout which contains a imageview and a gridlayout which contains three imagebutton.

[image]

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.prova.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.prova">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/profile" />

<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
    app:columnCount="3"
    app:orientation="horizontal"
    app:rowCount="1"
    app:useDefaultMargins="false" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@drawable/friend" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:maxHeight="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/fotocamera" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:src="@drawable/eventi" />
</android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

But i don't obtain the same result of the top of the image.
I've tried changing the gravity value and width value but nothing.
Can you help me??? (sorry for my bad english :P Thanks).

Comment: What is your result? Possibly post a screenshot because the layout is quite complex.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: This is the result http://it.tinypic.com/r/2rf9fdf/8
The three immagebutton into the gridlayout don't occupy all the horizontally space.

Answer (score 0):

I worked on your code to obtain this: http://it.tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2aj1cms&s=8#.UyhKXtT5OBM
It's a better result but i don't understand why there are s space between the imagebutton.
My code is this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.prova"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.prova.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="4" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/profile" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="3" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:weightSum="3" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/friend" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/fotocamera" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/eventi" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Aggiungi agli amici" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Any idea??

Comment: You might have some margin set somewhere - check out your themes, styles, dimens files in the values folder/s